# MVC4 Page without WebAPI

Tags: .net, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

Does anyone know of a way to start ASP.NET MVC 4 project without including all of that WebAPI junk?  I'd like to do some experimenting with Razor, you know make a simple page without having to bloat my source control / server without a bunch of crap I don't care about.  I looked for some templates, etc. but no luck.  Any ideas?

Comment: junk: noun: "anything that is regarded as worthless, meaningless, or contemptible; trash"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the existing template to create a project first.  I would then remove the components I didn't need, and [create a new template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xkh1wxd8.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You just create an empty project of ASP.NET MVC 4, and then:

1. Use nuget to remove package: "Microsoft ASP.NET Web API (RC)".
2. Remove the dedault route of Web API.

   ```
    routes.MapHttpRoute(
           name: "DefaultApi",
           routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
           defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
       );
   ```
3. Compile project again and removing some using errors to web api.

Answer (score 0):

The [ReallyEmptyASPNetMVCTemplate](http://haacked.com/archive/2012/01/10/a-really-empty-asp-net-mvc-3-project-template.aspx/) is also good, just make it MVC4 instead of MVC3.